# Calling into Chrome extension background / event pages

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've got an extension that successfully reads the current web page, extracts the data it needs, and builds a list of actions to take.
Currently they are presented to the user, to let them click links to carry them out. The downside to these links is that the second they click the link the new tab pops up, killing the extension's popup window and thus ending script execution. I also don't want the user to have to mindlessly click, click, click - I want to automate it.

So I'd like to hand off the list of actions to something that can continue executing even if the popup window is dismissed (with the user's full knowledge, of course).

I've seen about event and background pages - are either of these the right way to go? Or am I trying to do something impossible?

I tried creating an event page and I read that in order to communicate from the content script (popup.js - I think that's the right term?) to that event page, I need to use sendMessage(). But despite sending a message and having onMessage.addListener in the event page's script, I just get null for the response to the function supplied to sendMessage. An alert in the event addListener function (rather, the fact that it is not firing) proves that it is never getting there. I'm guessing this is because the event page isn't being loaded - but should that not happen when sendMessage is called? Should I be using the tab ID version of sendMessage?

So my questions are:

1. Are event or background pages the right way to hand off processing that can complete even when the popup is dismissed? If not, how?
2. How do I need to write the event page (and / or sendMessage call) to correctly have it loaded when sendMessage is called to ensure it picks up the message?
   And if I may sneak in a couple of other questions related to links...
3. Only left-clicking them works in the popup, despite them being perfectly standard anchor tags. How can I get them to respond to right-clicks as links in normal web pages do?
4. Is it possible to force a new tab to load in the background from the anchor tag, which would stop my extension's popup being killed off?

Sorry for the length.

Answer (score 0):

*Please try not to bundle questions in future.*

> 1) Are event or background pages the right way to hand off processing that can complete even when the popup is dismissed? If not, how?

Yes, background/event pages are precisely for that purpose - background processing.

> 2) How do I need to write the event page (and / or sendMessage call) to correctly have it loaded when sendMessage is called to ensure it picks up the message?

It's impossible to tell what's wrong with your code *without your code* (and please make a new question if you want to get help on that), but adding a listener for `onMessage` should be sufficient.

A background page is always loaded, and an event page (`"persistent": false`) is unloaded if idle, but Chrome remembers which events had listeners assigned and will call the page again if that event happens.

Debugging your background page from `chrome://extensions/` may help.

> 3) Only left-clicking them works in the popup, despite them being perfectly standard anchor tags. How can I get them to respond to right-clicks as links in normal web pages do?

No comments on this one. I'm reasonably sure that a custom click handler would get a right-click.

> 4) Is it possible to force a new tab to load in the background from the anchor tag, which would stop my extension's popup being killed off?

Yes, if you don't use `<a>` for navigation. You can use `chrome.tabs.create` in a click handler with `active: false`.